# GitHub for Windows crashes every time on startup on Windows 10

Tags: github, windows-10, github-for-windows

I've recently updated my computer and graphics driver to the latest version, and GitHub does not run anymore. Running it will cause GitHub to crash. I assume that GitHub has been unintentionally broken.

Here's the application error log.

```
Faulting application name: GitHub.exe, version: 3.0.12.0, time stamp: 0x56a69eea
Faulting module name: amdocl.dll, version: 10.0.1912.5, time stamp: 0x567ac8c3
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0023525b
Faulting process id: 0x1608
Faulting application start time: 0x01d15c401c7bc7b1
Faulting application path: C:\Users\Bryan See\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\XAE6DH98.VQY\H58NHLOV.P2N\gith..tion_317444273a93ac29_0003.0000_20a3dfa4ba8ba894\GitHub.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\amdocl.dll
Report Id: b3979569-4ead-4baf-8df7-9e7677ee1412
Faulting package full name:
```

I had to assume that the AMD driver is causing this, as I'm running Windows 10 64-bit with virtual desktop resolution is enabled. However, I couldn't get in touch with the support team at GitHub.

Comment: "I couldn't get in touch with the support team at GitHub." Unfortunately, you're going to have to keep trying. We're not GitHub support, and we don't have access to their source code. As a result there is very little that we can do to help with this problem. Good luck!

Comment: amdocl.dll = AMD OpenCL driver. look if the AMD control panel allows you to disable OpenCL for an exe

Comment: I've contacted GitHub support just now, and I hope they'll get back to me very shortly.